# Problema con Zona DNS usando Bind

Tags: dns

Tengo una mv con un servidor bind9 en ubuntu, tengo asignada la IP 10.33.1.3 para el servidor, y tengo el siguiente problema:

Segun el siguiente enunciado;

> El dominio asir01.net delegará la autoridad del subdominio
> fct.asir01.net en un servidor DNS cuyo nombre de dominio será
> ns1.fct.asir01.net y su IP será 10.44.1.10.

Pero al crear la zona db.asir01.net aparece el siguiente error:

```
root@server:~# named-checkzone 1.33.10.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/db.asir01.net /etc/bind/db.asir01.net:13: ignoring out-of-zone data (fct.asir01.net) /etc/bind/db.asir01.net:14: ignoring out-of-zone data (ns1.fct.asir01.net) zone 1.33.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1 OK root@server:~#
```

O bien:

```
zone asir01.net/IN: NS 'ns1.asir01.net' has no address records (A or AAAA) zone asir01.net/IN: not loaded due to errors
```

Este es mi archivo named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//
// Zonas de busqueda directas
zone "asir01.net"{
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.asir01.net";
};

//zone "seguridad.asir01.net"{
//     type master;
//     file "/etc/bind/db.seguridad.asir01.net";
//     allow-transfer {10.33.1.10;};
//};
//
//Zonas de busquedas inversas
zone "1.33.10.in-addr.arpa"{
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/db.10.33.1";
};
```

Y mi archivo /etc/bind/db.asir01.net:

```
;Ficherodb.asir01.net
$TTL    1D
@       IN      SOA     ns1.asir01.net. administrador.asir01.net.       (
                        1               ;Serial
                        604800          ;Refresh
                        86400           ;Retry
                        2419200         ;Expire
                        10800   )       ;NegativeCacheTTL(3Horas)
;ServidoresDNSdeldominio
        IN      NS      ns1.asir01.net.

;Delegacion
fct.asir01.net.         IN      NS      ns1.fct.asir01.net.
ns1.fct.asir01.net.     IN      A       10.44.1.10

;Hosts
01ASIR                  IN      A       10.33.1.5
server                  IN      A       10.33.1.3
;Alias
www     IN      CNAME   ns1
ftp     IN      CNAME   server
mail    IN      CNAME   server
```

Porque me puede dar ese error?

Comment: El primer error diria que siempre lo da cuando las ips son internas, yo no le daria importancia. En cuanto al segundo, segun veo ese dominio no existe realmente en la red, ni tampoco has creado su registro A en la zona `/etc/bind/db.asir01.net`, y diria que alli esta el error grave. Crealo y a ver que pasa. `ns1.asir01.net A ip` donde `ip` debe ser la IP donde corre el bind supongo.

Comment: Corrección: Aunque es evidente por si acaso lo digo. En lugar de `ns1.asir01.net A ip` es `ns1.asir01.net. IN A ip` (olvide el puntito final y el `IN`)